# Show / hide menu items in Android , based on Php server current time

Tags: php, android, laravel, postgresql

I was stucking in php code & not able to proceed. Based on selection of timing, menu items should be show /hide.

How to get the PHP current time from the server through API

For example : IDLY - (8 am to 10 am)
               After 11 am, idly should be disable or hidden

Comment: So what are you stuck with? What is the question?

Comment: to hide/show menus should be manage in your design side. not in php side

Comment: Android food menu items should be hide /show, based on php server current time..The menu items are displayed according to php API call. please help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `show/hide` the menu items using below code

```
Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_id1).setVisible(false);
nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_id2).setVisible(true);
. 
.
```

Comment: Based on php server current time , Android menu items should be hide / show

Comment: For example : Menu name - idly , timing - 8 am to 10 pm ...This menu item only should display.

Comment: So first of all get the current time from your server(through API). based on that time you can do whatever you want

Comment: How to store the bootstrap timepicker 'from' and 'to' time values in postgresql DB.

Comment: It should be a new question. post it as a separate question. So the experts of that field will help you.

Comment: how to get the current time from the server through API

Comment: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html